# Android:How to Intercept Sms when broadcast is non-ordered?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm working in intercept sms application. It was works fine in android 1.6 and up.But in android < 1.6 doesn't work.I think that the broadcast in android 1.5 is non-ordered and android:priority doesn't work. People has solution or other way to intercept sms?

Comment: Do you really need to support android 1.5?

Comment: Yes, my app required android 1.5 and up

Comment: android 1.5 is so extinct that it doesn't even appear anymore on the dashboard (http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) even 1.6 is ~0.1% of devices connecting to Play

Answer (score 1):

you can test if the broadcast is ordered by calling `isOrderedBroadcast()`, you'll know, which is better than think.

If a broadcast is not ordered, it cannot be intercepted, mostly because even if it could, you would have no way of being sure if your interception is of any use at all, as you have no idea  who has already received the broadcast.